# How to find non-trivial solution of a system of equations?

Tags: equation-solving

I have a system of four equations

```
 eqs4 := {(-5 + 2 c) E^(
     4 I c π) (E^(4 I c π) Subscript[x, 1] - Subscript[x, 
       4]) == (5 + 2 c) E^(
     12 I a c) (Subscript[x, 2] - 
       E^(4 I c π) Subscript[x, 3]), (-5 + 2 c) E^(
     6 I a c) (-E^(I b) + E^(6 I a c)) Subscript[x, 
     3] == (5 + 2 c) (1 - E^(I (b + 6 a c))) Subscript[x, 
     4], (-5 + 2 c) (-E^(2 I c (3 a + 2 π)) + E^(
       I (b + 8 c π))) Subscript[x, 
     2] == (5 + 2 c) (-E^(-6 I c (a - 2 π)) + E^(
       I (b + 8 c π))) Subscript[x, 1], 
   Subscript[x, 3] + 2 c (Subscript[x, 1] + Subscript[x, 3]) + 
     Subscript[x, 4] - Subscript[x, 
     1] - (5 + 2 c) Subscript[x, 2] == -2 c Subscript[x, 4]};
```

and I want to find the non-trivial solution of the system when $det=0$. I want to obtain $\left\{x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4\right\}$ in terms of other parameters.

Trying solve, I only obtain trivial solution zero:

```
Solve[eqs4, {Subscript[x, 1], Subscript[x, 2], Subscript[x, 3], 
   Subscript[x, 4]}] // 
 Simplify[#, 
   Assumptions -> 
    c ∈ Reals &&  c > 0  && b ∈ Reals &&  b > 0 && 
     a ∈ Reals &&  a > 0  && d ∈ Reals] &
```

Then, I try to ignore one of the equation and variables as follows

```
eqs3 := {(-5 + 2 c) E^(6 I a c) (-E^(I b) + E^(6 I a c)) Subscript[x, 
     3] == (5 + 2 c) (1 - E^(I (b + 6 a c))) Subscript[x, 
     4], (-5 + 2 c) (-E^(2 I c (3 a + 2 π)) + E^(
       I (b + 8 c π))) Subscript[x, 
     2] == (5 + 2 c) (-E^(-6 I c (a - 2 π)) + E^(
       I (b + 8 c π))) Subscript[x, 1], 
   Subscript[x, 3] + 2 c (Subscript[x, 1] + Subscript[x, 3]) + 
     Subscript[x, 4] - Subscript[x, 
     1] - (5 + 2 c) Subscript[x, 2] == -2 c Subscript[x, 4]};
```

and I get a solution

```
solution = 
  Solve[eqs3, {Subscript[x, 2], Subscript[x, 3], Subscript[x, 4]}] // 
   Simplify[#, 
     Assumptions -> 
      c ∈ Reals &&  c > 0  && b ∈ Reals &&  b > 0 && 
       a ∈ Reals &&  a > 0  && d ∈ Reals] &;
```

But when I try to verify this solution, one of them is not verified.

```
eqs4 /. solution // 
 Simplify[#, 
   Assumptions -> 
    c ∈ Reals &&  c > 0  && b ∈ Reals &&  b > 0 && 
     a ∈ Reals &&  a > 0  && d ∈ Reals] &
```

Does anybody have a suggestion on how I can find a solution of this system?

Answer (score 3):

There are no *general* non-trivial solutions. First I've replaced the `Subscript`'s with `x[1],x[2],x[3],x[4]`. Then I subtracted the rhs of each equation so each equation would equal zero, and I discarded the `== 0` part for brevity.

```
eqs4 = {
  (-5 + 2 c) E^(4 I c π) (E^(4 I c π) x[1] - x[4]) - (5 + 2 c) E^(12 I a c) (x[2] - E^(4 I c π) x[3]),
  (-5 + 2 c) E^(6 I a c) (-E^(I b) + E^(6 I a c)) x[3] - (5 + 2 c) (1 - E^(I (b + 6 a c))) x[4],
  (-5 + 2 c) (-E^(2 I c (3 a + 2 π)) + E^(I (b + 8 c π))) x[2] - ((5 + 2 c) (-E^(-6 I c (a - 2 π)) + E^(I (b + 8 c π))) x[1]), 
  x[3] + 2 c (x[1] + x[3]) + x[4] - x[1] - (5 + 2 c) x[2] + 2 c x[4]
};
```

Then I obtained a matrix with `CoefficientArrays[eqs4, Array[x, 4]]` - the first element is all zero as there are no constant terms, so we can do:

```
mtx = CoefficientArrays[eqs4, Array[x, 4]] // Normal // Last
FullSimplify[mtx.Array[x, 4] == eqs4] (* confirm it works: True *)
```

Notice that `NullSpace[mtx]` is empty.
Also I cannot find an `{a,b,c}` such where $\det(M)=0$ except at $a=0,b=0,c=0$:

```
FindInstance[Det[mtx] == 0, {a, b, c}, Complexes]
(* {{a -> 0, b -> 0, c -> 0}} *)

FindInstance[Det[mtx] == 0, {a, b, c}, Complexes, 2]
(* FindInstance::nsmet: The methods available to FindInstance are
   insufficient to find the requested instances or prove they do not exist. *)
```

We can try to find the `NullSpace` of any triple of equations:

```
mtx3way = Subsets[mtx, {3}];
nsp3way = Simplify[First@NullSpace[#]] & /@ mtx3way;
```

Each of `Simplify[mtx.nsp3way[[1]]]`, `Simplify[mtx.nsp3way[[2]]]`, `Simplify[mtx.nsp3way[[3]]]`, `Simplify[mtx.nsp3way[[4]]]` should have three zeros and one complicated expression in `a,b,c`.

Looking at the first one, we can find an `a,b,c` which satisfies it in the `Complexes`, but any attempt to do so in the `Reals` will fail:

```
t1 = Simplify[mtx.nsp3way[[1]]] // Last
i1 = FindInstance[t1 == 0, {a, b, c}, Complexes]
```

---

If you are prepared to fix `{a,b,c}` to specific values, finding many non-trivial solutions is easy, for example, rigging a=0, b=0, c=0:

```
sols = FindInstance[
  FullSimplify[eqs4 /. {a -> 0, b -> 0, c -> 0}] == {0, 0, 0, 0}, 
  Array[x, 4], Reals, 100]
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, in general and for all four variables yes, but it should be a way to obtain three of them in terms of one variable. Something like finding an unnormalized solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a nontrivial solution. Let me develop the thought of @flinty further.

Expanding Det[mtx] shows, it gets much simple with certain a,b

```
det1 = Det[mtx] // Expand

dd = Det[mtx] /. a -> 2 Pi /. b -> 8 c Pi // Expand    

ComplexExpand[Im@dd, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}]
```

The result of that ComplexExpand are all Sin[8 c Pi], Sin[12 c Pi], implying c should be c==1. Bingo!

```
Solve[Thread[eqs4 == 0] /. a -> 2 Pi /. b -> 8 c Pi /. c -> 1, 
    Array[x, 4]]   

(*   Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables. >>

{{x[3] -> x[1], x[4] -> -((4 x[1])/3) + (7 x[2])/3}}   *)
```

**Edit**

All multiples of b==2 Pi are allowed.
For a all multiples of Pi are allowed, also multiples of Pi/3.

Comment: By fixing {a,b,c} to certain values, e.g {a -> 2 Pi, b -> 8 Pi, c -> 1}, it is easily solvable. I thought the question asked for the x[i] in terms of arbitrary {a,b,c}. Otherwise:  `FindInstance[
 FullSimplify[eqs4 /. {a -> 0, b -> 0, c -> 1}] == {0, 0, 0, 0}, 
 Array[x, 4], Reals, 25]` finds loads of them.

Comment: `{a -> 0, b -> 0,c->0} ` are not allowed due to conditions. I think the question was to find (conditions for) a,b,c where the xi have no trivial solution. Since Reduce didn't do the job for me, i found some a,b,c by intuition.